# Expandable tableview delay when expanding and collapsing

Tags: ios, swift, performance, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a collectionView consisting of 100 imageViews INSIDE my expandable tableView.
When I click on a cell of my tableView (to expand it), I change the height of the tableview to 4000 to display my collectionView of 100 imageViews
When I click again (collapse) i reduce the height of tableView so that the collectionView isn't visible anymore

Both these cases result in a delay that would ruin the user experience

How can i make it more smooth and is there a better way to go about this than what i'm currently doing?

I am using:

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

to update the height of my tableview cell.

Comment: show the full code

Comment: Place a breakpoint on the line where you reload the rows. When executed, check what thread you are on. If it is not the main thread, then you need to add a call to do so.

Comment: It did become slightly faster but still slow  AND
it's initially messing up the background color i set around my imageViews

Comment: So that indicates you have a threading issue. Without more code to see, it is pure guesswork to troubleshoot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48442971/ios-how-to-create-expandable-tableview-in-swift-without-using-third-parties-and/51964908#51964908 check my answer here , if any help :)